# Disable HTML5 <video> playsinline for iPad

Tags: html, ios, video

I would like to explore if it is possible to disable `playsinline` for HTML5 `<video>` on iOS, specifically for iPad. My video tag (below) does NOT include `playsinline`, as I wish the video to open in the native iOS video player.

Since iOS10, Apple have enabled the ability to use `playsinline`, however for this project I do not want this. During testing however, it seems that regardless of wether or not the attribute exists, on iPad the video will play inline regardless and I would like to disable this, forcing the native iOS player instead (just like on iPhone).

I found the [following article](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiwebview/1617960-allowsinlinemediaplayback), which states: 'When adding a video element to a HTML document on the iPhone, you must also include the playsinline attribute. The default value for iPhone is false and the default value for iPad is true."

The above suggests that this is the reason for my problem, but I'm unsure how to resolve?

Many thanks.

```
<video src="myurl.com" preload loop></video>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are happy to have the same behaviour on all devices, you can explicitly assign a value to the attribute in your HTML5 code:

```html
<video src="myurl.com" preload loop playsinline="false"></video>
```